# AFNetworking and Push Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, afnetworking

I am working on an application which `GET` and `POST` information to a server. I am doing so using `AFNetworking` framework. My aim is to push a notification to a client whenever someone posts new info to the server. Eg: a new grade is published, the student who's grade was published must receive a notification on his iDevice. 
Although I am not familiar with how Apple Push Notification works, from what I read I concluded that I need to add server side code in order to trigger a notification.
Note that I don't have access to the server. Service is provided by Fedena.
Any suggestions or hints from where to start?

Comment: This is still quite relevant: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APNS needs a server in order to work. The usual flow goes like this:

1. The iOS Application asks user to enable push notifications
2. Upon access granted, a device token is generated and then must be sent to the server.
3. Your server must be setup with the proper APNS certificates generated from the Apple Developer site
4. Then in your server's, when a new post is created, you need to add some logic where you load all the APNS token you've received already and then send the notification to the devices.

This is a very simple flow description but I guess you understood that you need to have access to the server to be able to do what you are trying to achieve.

Some third parties exists to handle push notifications (like Urban Airship), but those push notifications are usually pushed manually from a person, and not triggered from a server event

Comment: Thank you. Isn't there any other way to add push notifications to an app? Using parse push for example?

Comment: I have never tried parse push, but then it would either be manual push (i.e you enter the comment you want to push to device) or might be event related to parse db, but I am really unsure about it

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you can use secondary server of your own as intermediate and use it as infrastructure back bone.You can use SignalR library. Use secondary server as to create connection between two devises. One client will push events and another client will listen to events.
Here is the [link](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC) to the signalR library code written in IOS.

I am currently using these library. What you can do is start hub and connection using these library. 
This library allows invoking method on server. Something like this.

> [_hub invoke:@"MehtodName" withArgs:params];

What i would do is to create event registry on server. So one client can listen to event on server and other can push events or vice versa. 
So your student device can invoke method "subscribe to events" and server will add it into the registry list. You can create secondary service "Publish Events". Grade publisher can publish via calling this method. Here publish events will look up registry and find interested clients and call desired method on client.

Read more about signalr through this [site](http://www.asp.net/signalr).

Benefit of using Signalr Over APNS.

> - Cost Effective. As this will save you money which you might have to pay    to Apple for pushing notification.
> - Can Easily make it cross plateform in future. Just have to impletement similar library in Android/Windows.
> - Quicker as the data does not travel to apple server    from your server.
> - Worst case you can fallback to apns any day, just put push notification code in any of your secondary server methods.

I have done battery and performance testing as well and works perfectly fine.

If you wanna know, here how it handles connection which is very reliable.

> SRAutoTransport chooses the best supported transport for both client
>   and server. This achieved by falling back to less performant
>   transports. The default transport fallback is:
>
> 1. SRWebSocketTransport
> 2. SRServerSentEventsTransport
> 3. SRLongPollingTransport

Let me know if you have anyother question. i am currently doing similar work, might be able to help you with your issue.

Comment: Can you explain more about this?

Comment: What would like to know more about this ?
This is replacement of push notification service of APNS or Google. Set up your server to maintain subscriber list with key,sub key in other words client interested in listening to events published on particular key, sub key.  One client will post on this key, sub key.  Your server designated events on other client. Infrastructure is little lengthy to create but once created works like charm. I have given important link in my answer. If you have any specific problem or trouble figuring out, feel free to post question.